# Restrictions on attendees for OAuth Service Accounts in Google Calendar API v3?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a Service Account created in a Super Admin account on my domain.  I'm able to connect to the Google Calendar API v3 using the "Domain-wide Delegation of Authority" model provided by Google here (https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation).  I can list my own events, list the events of others.  No problem.

However, I am running into issues when inserting events with external attendees.  To be clear, I can insert events just fine when including attendees within my own domain.  (Aside from mysteriously blank exceptions that need to be caught!)

I can successfully insert a few events like this with external attendees, but soon, I start getting:

```
HttpError 403: "Calendar usage limits exceeded"
```

If I let it sit for a few hours, I can run it again and get a few events to insert, but then it starts with this error again.

Note:  I'm not reaching the per-user quota and I'm nowhere near the daily courtesy limit.  I do also have a sleep in the code between inserts.  The body of the event is also confirmed to be well-formed.

I've isolated this issue down to the event attendees being external, seeing as how I do not get these errors when running the exact same code limited to attendees on the same domain.  Can someone explain why this is occurring?

Comment: I've reproduced this issue in a different GAB domain.  I've tried to add the service account email to the users on which I'm inserting events, with Owner access, which did not solve anything.  I've opened a bug report:  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3363

Comment: Hi Daniel, you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Here is my solution step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715242/5212039

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're reaching the limit of 5 requests/second? How many times a second are you attempting your inserts? I have not found (here: [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing)) that the Calendar API has a per-second usage limit, but some other APIs do have such a restriction... either 5/sec or 10/sec api calls...

Comment: Good idea, but I have sleeps in the code to throttle, you can increase the requests/second limit in the API Console, and most importantly, the API fails in a consistent way, regarding external attendees.  If events only have internal attendees, I can consistently insert mass amounts of events, say ~2,000+.  (I've never actually came anywhere close to the daily courtesy limit, so I'm not sure how it behaves if you push it.)