# In Python, how do you use the Google Apps Domain Key to connect to Google API?

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I can't connect to my Google Calendar using the Domain Key, i.e. the consumer key with the same name as the domain name.

I'm using the the OAuth2WebServerFlow, Credentials and Storage objects as guided here:  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id="domain.com",
                           client_secret=<Consumer Secret>,
                           scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')
```

But, I just get an "invalid_client" error when I go to the website for authentication.

Does anybody have any tips for getting this to work?  I have no issues getting OAuth keys that I generate from the API console working.  But, I'm struggling with the domain key, specifically.  Is there something special that you have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for OAuth 2.0 and hence you need the actual Client ID, not your domain. (It seems like you're getting this mixed up with OAuth 1.0 a bit, but maybe I'm misunderstanding.)

Check out the Google APIs Console [docs](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2) for more information on what a Client ID is and where you can find it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I understand what a Client ID is and the domain key in GAB is a Client ID.  I'm trying to figure out how to connect using it.

Comment: It seems like "TwoLeggedOAuthCredentials" no longer exists.  I can't find it in the google-api-python-client v1.1.

Comment: Sorry for comment spamming here.  Kinda ridiculous that you can't edit a comment after 5 minutes.  My previous comment is in reference to this page, where it explains how to do what I want to do, except I can't get it to work because I cannot find "TwoLeggedOAuthCredentials."  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins

Comment: Yes, and the article mentions "2-legged OAuth 1.0". As I said, we don't support OAuth 1.0; it has been deprecated in favor of OAuth 2.0.

Comment: So, I should use OAuth 2.0 to connect using the domain key?  If so, how do I go about doing that, exactly?  Whenever I try that using OAuth2WebServerFlow, I get a page that reports "invalid_client."  If I'm missing something obvious, I apologize.  But, it seems that the deprecated way is much better documented than the non-deprecated way.

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible to use the GAB Domain Key in OAuth 2.0 because you'd instead use a Service Account?  Using the Domain Key is only available in OAuth 1.0?

Comment: Yes, service accounts are your way to go.

Comment: I'm trying to use a service account, actually, but running into a weirdo issue where external attendees on inserted events makes it blow up... which is why I was looking for alternatives.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619763/restrictions-on-attendees-for-oauth-service-accounts-in-google-calendar-api-v3 -- Have you seen that before?

Answer (score 0):

Use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, and specify the user you want to impersonate with the 'prn' parameter:

http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials-class.html

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106

Comment: That doesn't work for the GAB domain key though.  I asked specifically about the domain key, respectfully.

Comment: As bossylobster has already pointed out to you, the GAB domain key is OAuth 1.0 and is deprecated. The links I gave you explain how to accomplish the same thing using OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @JoeGregorio `prn` has been deprecated in favor of `sub`. The value `prn` was used by Google before the spec was final and now it is final. AFAIK both work, but `sub` is the future, not `prn`.