# Google Calendar API Service Account Error

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Im getting this error

```
{ "error": 
     { "errors": 
         [
            { "domain": "calendar", "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts", "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." } 
         ], 
         "code": 403,
         "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
      } 
}
```

Already followed this
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

im using this library and im running it on laravel 5.7: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

What could be the fix for this. Please help.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide more information about how are you authenticating your service account? Are you actually trying to impersonate another user? Please paste some code to try to reproduce your problem as [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) indicates.  Also try to improve your question following the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Raserhin Same issue here, didn't want to create a new one. I authenticate with GoogleCredential (in .NET Core backend) and the service account doesn't impersonate someone. It has domain-wide authority and scopes [Calendar, CalendarEvents]. Everything works (even creating Calendar Events) but the moment I add EventAttendees when creating an event, it returns the error OP posted.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, you don't only need to give the service account domain wide delegation you need to "impersonate" a person in your domain, if you are setting everything up but not doing that last step you would be executing your code on behalf the service account (which is not permitted in this method for spam and security reasons) not an user of your domain.

Comment: @Raserhin Thanks for your reply! How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you just want some pointers you can take a look at these pages ([1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and [2](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)). If you need more than that maybe create another question, posting your code and explaining your set up and problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, followed all the steps in given link - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar. Service account created, and 
Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation. But still same error.

Comment: @Elmo Montilla do you have resolved your issue?

Answer (score 25):

Here are the steps to follow to make this work:

**Enable Domain-Wide Delegation in your service account**

**1 - Provide calendar scopes to your service account**

- Go to https://admin.google.com/ and login with G Suite account.
- Go to Security -> API Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation
- Add new => Set the client ID of your service account (The one that's only numbers)
- Set the following scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar

**2 - Your user needs to have the role Service Account Token Creator**

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin then
- Select your project and go to IAM in the left menu.
- Select the account that you will use to impersonate
- Click on edit
- Add role Service Account Token Creator
- Enable domain delegation for the account according to https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation, section *To enable G Suite domain-wide delegation, follow these steps*.

**3 - Create a Calendar in the account that you will impersonate**

Service accounts don't have calendars so you have to create your own calendar

- Login in https://calendar.google.com/ with the email that you want to own the calendar (I used a different account, not the same that I was going to impersonate, maybe it works using a calendar in the impersonated account)
- Create a calendar
- Share the calendar with the service account with permissions to modify and manage the calendar
- Share the calendar with the account you will impersonate with permissions to modify and manage the calendar

**Create google client**

- Authenticate your service account. (I used the JSON Key, I am not sure if other authentication works for this purpose)

Code sample: (I used PHP but I assume that other languages are very similar so you can use this as guideline)

**Note that using some email for IMPERSONALIZATION is crucial. Otherwise, the 403 error will remain, use it for authentication, see the Maksym Kalin response for details.**

```
$google_client = new Google_Client();
$google_client->setAuthConfig($LOCATION_OF_JSON_KEY);
$google_client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
$google_client->setSubject('EmailToImpersonate@SomeAddress.com');
$google_client->setApplicationName("YourApplicationName");
$google_client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, \Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS]);
```

**Create Event with people invited :) and Enjoy!**

**Note:** *With this approach you can create events and invite people to it. Keep in mind the limits of the G Suite https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486 so if you want to create many events you will need to have a pool of service accounts with a pool of calendars.*

Comment: On my side (using PHP api 2.7), it was not enough: I also had to set some permission on a place that seems to be not documented on the API doc. This permission must be set from page: https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation : You must give permission on the 2 scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'. Removing them make the API fails again with the same error "403 Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority". Giving "domain wide validation" to the service account was not enough.

Comment: Heck yeah brother. This solved my issue. Step 2 is crucial and poorly documented.

Comment: how if i don't have a G Suite account?

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of granting domain-wide authority to a Service Account is for these accounts to be able to access data **on behalf of** users in the domain.

If you grant it domain-wide authority but are not "impersonating" any account, the Service Account is acting as if you hadn't granted this authority: it is trying to access its own Calendars.

When the Service Account impersonates another user in the domain (that is, when it acts on behalf of the user), the Service Account can access the resources this user can access.

To impersonate another user, you have to specify the user's email address.
In my case, I use Node.JS library and my impersonation code looks like this:

```
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  config.client_email,
  null,
  config.private_key,
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"],
  "!!! user email to impersonate !!!!",
);
```

What is more, in case you need to fill attendees[] array, you have to authorize the service account to send emails. Because you get unauthorized error.

To do it you need to add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send scope on your G Suite domain’s Admin console.

You can find more here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/14170493

Comment: This is a huge missing part of the puzzle, thanks Maksym! I had everything else configured correctly according to the answer form Anathorn except this.

Answer (score 3):

Just for information

In my case, on Node.js, i followed intructions from @Anathorn, but i kept getting

> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

then i add on my auth line the email what should i supplant, and it worked.

```
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    CREDENTIALS.client_email,`
    null,
    CREDENTIALS.private_key,
    SCOPES,
    "admin@domain.com",
    "12345678987654321"
);
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. "12345678987654321" is the client_id specified in Google Service Account file.

Answer (score 2):

For those using the googleapis-nodejs-client library a solution was brought on [a issue in the google-auth-library-nodejs github page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/916#issuecomment-711609374).

Doing all conf steps from @Anathorn and logging the service account this way worked for me :

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
keyFile: './service.json',
scopes: [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'
],
clientOptions: {
  subject: 'email@email.com'
},
```

});

EDIT:
It only works locally !

From what I could gather, you can't use App Default Credendials while running on GCP (Cloud functions for me) with Domain Wide Authority, only using auth with JWT should be working.

Comment: You saved me after I wasted around two days.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that may be running into this issue, for me it was a combination of Anathorn's answer and  Maksym Kalin's answer. It was because I was not impersonating the users email address.

A user previously has tried to commit the same library you are using (I am using it too), but it was declined by the repo owner (how sad)

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar/pull/97

Anyway, his code here was how I fixed it on my end.

Good luck for anyone else who has this issue, its been a pain in my ass for far too long.

Comment: I've done all spets in this post, but when i try so create a calendar event with attendee i have this erros: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." } Do you have some ideat that what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yilo's solution works correctly :-)