# How to create a Google calendar event for non-workspace-google account, if the event was created through Service Account(Google Calendar API)?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

I am able to create an event in Google Calendar using Service account and Google Calendar API, where Project and Service Account is created in Google Workspace admin account and in the same account, I have enabled domain-wide delegation property. I haven't created separate calendar and haven't given access to Service account. If I use my workspace-google account in createDelegated(), with this event is getting created in 'abc@myworkspace.com' calendar and 'created by' property is also the same for every attendee I have added.

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)).createScoped(SCOPES)
                    .createDelegated("abc@myworkspace.com");
```

So my question is what if I need to create event for non-workspace google account(lets say def@gmail.com)

Can I pass 'def@gmail.com' into the createDelegated()? If I do, I am getting,

```
Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
```

So how to create event for non-workspace google account?

Note : App type is still 'Internal' in OAuth consent screen.

Could someone explain what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

### A service account with domain-wide delegation can only be used for domains

A Google Workspace account is a domain, a personal consumer account is not a domain.

Consequently, you can not perform a request on behalf of a consumer account user via a service account.

Instead, you would need to create the event directly as `def@gmail.com` similar to the [documentation sample](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#examples).

Comment: Could you tell me in this how the **service** object got created? I mean to say which way it is created? is it not created with the Service Account key?

Comment: @TheSagya the actual mechanism by which service account authorization is achieved is a little more complicated then just the Service account key  Try reading though this [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)  Pay close attention to how the JWT is created.

Comment: No, when using [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) workflow the service object is created as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java#step_2_set_up_the_sample). For this flow you need to download and use the user cedentials json opposed to the service account key. The user need to to manually authorize the app as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java#step_3_run_the_sample).

Answer (score 0):

No you can only delgate to an account on your domain

```
createDelegated("abc@myworkspace.com");
```

You can not delgate to a standard google account as there would be no way for you to configure the permissions

[perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth#perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority)

[Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

> Note: Only users with access to the Admin APIs can access the Admin SDK Directory API, therefore your service account needs to impersonate one of those users to access the Admin SDK Directory API. Additionally, the user must have logged in at least once and accepted the Google Workspace Terms of Service.

## Owner vs attendee.

A service account properly delegated.  Will have permission to create an event on behalf of a user in the domain that they have been delegated permission.

Example:  I have delegated permission to my service account to user User1@myDomain.com.  For all intensive purposed the service account now has all permissions of User1.  So the service account can create a new event on behalf of user1 and invite anyone to the event they choose.

As there is no way to set up deligation to user2@gmail.com there is no way for the service account to act like this user as it is a standard gmail user.

The only way for an application to create an event on behalf of user2@gmail.com would be to use Oauth2 and request consent of User2@gmail.com to access their private data.   Then the application would be able to create a new event on behalf of User2@gmail.com.

Remember this is creating an event.  There is nothing stopping the service account delegated as user1@mydomain.com from inviting user2@gmail.com to the event.  user2@gmail.com will then be notified that they have been invited to the event they can then decide if they want to attend or not if they accept it then it will appear in their google calendar account.   Notice how user2@gmail.com had to manually accept this.   User1@mydomain.com did not have to manually accept that the event was created in their google calendar as the service account was acting on their behalf.

Comment: Could you refer me the link where I can able to create event for Standard google account with API? which should be server to server communication and no consent screen should be there to the Standard google account?

Comment: You cant. Service accounts only work with Workspace accounts.   If you want to create an event in my Google calendar account you need my permission to get that permission you will need to go though Oauth2 authorization and request permission.   [Google calendar java Oauth2 sample](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java)

Comment: Okay, now I have created a service account and I've used it's JSON key for authorisation and with that I am able to create event in my calendar(it's my workspace account). In this event I have added my Standard google account(non-workspace account) as a attendee and I am able to see the specific event in my standard google account's calendar where created by property is my workspace account. And there was no permission asked to my standard google account.

Comment: That's because you have added the standard user as an attendee.  That user probably got an email and had to accept that event.  There is a difference between an attendee and an owner of the event.   You can not directly create an event in my Google calendar account where by i am the owner without my permission.    You can invite me to an event that you are owner of and if i accept it i will be added.

Comment: Yes, First of all I have used Standard google account(A) as a attendee and there was no acceptance process, still event was created in the Calendar as a attendee of an event. This thing is Okay, Actually I think you understood my problem here now, I need to create an event which can(OR must) be created in my workspace account calendar only but it should be created in a way that other attendees(apart from standard account(A)) should get the event created in their calendar as attendee only but it will show owner is Standard Google account(A), is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760959/google-calendar-api-service-account-error Can we relate this with my scenario?