# have an error while sending invite email using google calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, google-admin-settings-api

```
Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority
```

I see the error and searched lot but no solution was useful for me and I still see the error.
I don't have any issue on creating an event with service account but can't invite any user

I already added my client id in the Security > Access and data control > API Controls.
In the Domain wide delegation pane, Manage Domain Wide Delegation.
No changes I see

I already followed these steps and no changes applied.

From your Google Workspace domain’s Admin console, go to Main menu menu > **Security** > **Access and data control** > **API Controls**.

In the Domain wide delegation pane, select Manage Domain Wide Delegation.

**Click Add new.**

In the **Client ID** field, enter the service account’s Client ID. You can find your service account’s **client ID** in the **Service accounts page.**

In the OAuth scopes (comma-delimited) field, enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example, if your application needs domain-wide full access to the Google Calendar API, enter:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

**Click Authorize.**

Comment: It seems you have the same concern as this one, have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760959/google-calendar-api-service-account-error

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be going on here is that although the domain wide delegation has been done correctly no impersonation is being done on the code itself.

The impersonation actually happens directly from the code as its purpose is to determine which user sends the calendar invite since the service account is not really a user.

For the actual setup I believe this might come in handy: [https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md#preparing-to-make-an-authorized-api-call:~:text=If%20you%20have%20delegated%20domain%2Dwide%20access%20to%20the%20service%20account%20and%20you%20want%20to%20impersonate%20a%20user%20account%2C%20specify%20the%20email%20address%20of%20the%20user%20account%20using%20the%20method%20setSubject](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md#preparing-to-make-an-authorized-api-call:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20delegated%20domain%2Dwide%20access%20to%20the%20service%20account%20and%20you%20want%20to%20impersonate%20a%20user%20account%2C%20specify%20the%20email%20address%20of%20the%20user%20account%20using%20the%20method%20setSubject)

I hope it helps!